# "er" verwenden, um sich auf "man" beziehen

Tags: standard-german

Kann man „er“ verwenden, um sich auf „man“ zu beziehen, z.B.:

> Man kann im Internet mit seinen Freunden sprechen, sogar wenn er wenig Zeit hat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, kann man nicht.

*man* ist ein *Indefinitpronomen*, d.h. es adressiert niemanden bestimmten und u.U. auch mehrere Personen. Würde man "er" (ein definites Pronomen) damit verwenden, adressiert man jemanden bestimmten, der eindeutig spezifiziert ist - Die "Zielgruppe" ist nicht dieselbe.

Deinen Beispielsatz formuliert man am besten, indem man bei *man* bleibt:

> Man kann im Internet mit seinen Freunden sprechen, sogar wenn man wenig Zeit hat

Comment: he, ich hätte gedacht, der Beispielsatz hätte richtig formuliert "Man kann im Internet mit seinen Freunden sprechen, sogar wenn diese wenig Zeit haben" lauten müssen. Deine Interpretation ist aber wohl die gemeinte.

Comment: Die Frage war “kann man?” und ironischer weise nicht gerade *kann er*? Ich seje zwar ein, dass OP's Beispiel falsch klingt, doch vorausgesetzt *man* < *Mann* wäre die richtige Herleitung, was ich bezweifle, hätte meinereiner möglicherweise auf etwas Mehr gehofft.

Answer (score 1):

Das Personalpronomen *er* kann sich nicht auf *man* beziehen, sondern, wie schon gesagt wurde, man benutzt auch *man* dafür (solange ein Nominativ passt):

- Wenn *man* nicht weiß, was *man* machen soll...

Hier ist zwar keine klar bestimmte Einzelperson gemeint, aber *man* steht in beiden Vorkommen trotzdem für jeweils dieselben Personen (auch wenn man sonst wenig über sie weiß). Und weil dieses Muster möglich ist, verhält sich *man* tatsächlich als ein Personalpronomen, es ist kein Indefinitpronomen ( https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalisierendes_Personalpronomen ). Nur ein besonderer Typ von Personalpronomen.

Ich glaube, die Frage kommt daher, dass *sein* sich auf *man* beziehen kann, so wie es sich sonst auf *er* beziehen kann. Es gibt aber keine besondere Verbindung zwischen *er* und *sein*, sondern *sein* passt immer, solange das grammatische Geschlecht maskulin singular ist, sogar bei Indefinitpronomen ("wer alles" fragt sogar nach einer Gruppe, aber grammatisch ist es Einzahl, das reicht):

- *Er* hat *sein* Handy verloren
- *Jemand* hat *sein* Handy verloren
- Bitte melden: *Wer* hat alles *sein* Handy verloren?
- *Niemand* hat *sein* Handy verloren.
- niemand, *der* *sein* Handy verloren hat...
- Wenn *man* *sein* Handy verloren hat...

Answer (score -5):

Im Prinzip geht das. Es gibt hier bereits einige Antworten zu einer ähnlichen Frage, ob bspw. *das Mädchen* später im Text auch als *sie* angesprochen werden kann.

Aber: Wenn man bereit ist, Genus und Numerus mit Pronomen anstelle eines Nomens genauer zu bezeichnen, besteht in erster Linie gar kein Grund für den indefiniten Ansatz mit *man*.

Comment: Wenn ich Sätze lese wie "ich war mit dem Kind spazieren bis er müde war" dreht sich bei mir alles um. Das klingt doof und ist falsch. Es gibt in diesem Satz nichts wozu "er" passen würde, da ist nur das "Kind" das man mit "es" referenzieren kann. *"Wenn man bereit ist, Genus und Numerus mit Pronomen anstelle eines Nomens genauer zu bezeichnen"* - das geht nicht immer. Wenn allgemein ausgedrückt werden soll dass irgendeine Person mit Freunden sprechen kann, dann gibt es keine brauchbare Alternative zu "man". Die Verwendung von "Er" oder "Sie" erfordert wieder einen Bezug, den es nicht gibt.

Comment: @puck bist du nicht mehr ganz Frisch? Vielzählige Antworten bestätigen, dass z.B. "Da ist ein Mädchen. Sie interessiert das Gelaber nicht" durchaus möglich ist. "Da ist ein Mädchen, das [*die] ..." würde mich zwar stören, wohl wegen des direkten Kontaktes an der Wortfuge, das betrifft die Beispiele jedoch nicht: "Ich war mit dem Mädchen spazieren, bis sie müde war" klingt für mich normal. Übrigens, "Wenn allgemein ausgedrückt werden soll dass irgendeine Person mit Freunden sprechen kann, ..." dann schreib halt deine eigene Antwort.

Comment: Ich bin schon noch "frisch", da scheint dir der Ton aus irgendeinem "sozialen" Medium reingerutscht zu sein :-) Welche vielzähligen Antworten meinst du denn? Für mich klingt es jedenfalls absolut falsch. Dass manche es trotzdem verwenden macht es nicht besser. In manchen Bereichen und Gesellschaftsschichten hört man einiges ("tu ma die Oma winken" und so), was trotz aller Verwendung nicht passt und für andere eher in einer der unteren Schubladen landet.

Comment: @puck du bist seit 5 Jahren an Bord. In der Zeit kam die Frage häufiger auf. Wenn du zu unfrisch bist zu suchen, dann ist das nicht meine Schuld. Zur richtigen Antwort führt es jedenfalls nicht, daher erübrigen sich die Links und unterdessen auch jedes Entgegenkommen auf deine rhetorische Frage, als ob du irgendeinen Grund hättest, der du noch nie eine Frage gestellt hast, als ob du einer von den vom Himmel gefallenen Meistern wärst, die bereits alles wissen.

Comment: Ich habe nie gesagt dass ich es besser weiß, nur dass es für mich falsch klingt. Als native speaker spreche und empfinde ich nicht nach Regeln, sondern nach Gewohnheit anhand dem wie andere auch sprechen. Auf "ich hab Recht, will aber nicht wenigstens ein Beispiel zeigen" hab ich keine Lust. Übrigens die Downvotes lassen vermuten dass andere das vielleicht doch auch als falsch empfinden.

Comment: Schwachsinn. Die Downvotes folgten nachdem du den Ton vorgegeben und ich dich dementsprechend zünftig beleidigt habe. Das Beispiel aus der Frage selbst ist unmissverständlich und in diesem Sinne nicht falsch. Dein Appeal to Emotion ist schlicht unsachlich. Es gilt nicht Recht zu haben, sondern der Frage etwas positives entgegenzusetzen. Darüber hinaus habe ich lediglich festgestellt, dass die Frage nicht hinreichend begründet ist. Damit erübrigt es sich, das was Tofro geantwortet hatte zu wiederholen.